# xcopy to a file instead of a directory, can it be reversed?

Tags: xcopy

yeah, I did this:

xcopy * . * d:\save

The directory didn't exist and so a I have a file called 'save' ..
Is it possible to extract that or xcopy /? back to the original files ?

Thanks.

Comment: Xcopy is not destructive. Your original files should be where they where when you started. Just delete the "save" file.

Comment: Absolutely, except after moving everything I wanted to then I bulldozed the hard drive. I suppose the question is: Can i restore from a file xcopy created ?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. When you say "bulldozed" do you mean erased or formatted? You could always try a program like Recuvia or other file recovery programs if you haven't formatted the drive. Or you could use one of the unformat utilities (can't remember any since I keep several generations of image backups). BTW did I mention you do have backups don't you?

Comment: I formatted the drive. So, my next question is: Why is there a command line switch to save to **file** or a **directory**? ....why give and option?